# WebRTC - Optimising multiple video streams

Tags: html, webrtc

Good day. I am trying to build a web-based live streaming chat room, which needs to support up to 51 concurrent users. I am currently facing a issue, where the client's browser takes a performance hit when decoding multiple video streams. Is there anyway i can improve the client's browser performance while supporting as many user's as possible?

My only requirement is to support up to 51 users in the room, I am open to any ideas and suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest some practice. But, maybe it is hard to reach up to 51 users in only client environment. So before try it, also consider media server which is for video conference just like your requirement.

### MCU/SFU Media Server for Video Conference

- https://mediasoup.org
- https://janus.conf.meetecho.com
- http://www.medooze.com

### Optimization

You can optimize for performance. But I'm not really sure it is possible to serve up to 51 peers in same document.

#### Low resolution

Such like a 320x240 resolution. It use less resource each p2p clients. You can set with media constraints.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/

```
{
    "audio": true,
    "video": {
        "width": "320",
        "height": "240"
    }  
}
```

#### H264

WebRTC can use H264 which is cisco's openh264 software codec. Some report said it is use less cpu power then VP8 that is default codec of WebRTC.

- https://www.chriskranky.com/webrtc-impacts-on-battery-life/

You can change codec to manipulate SDP.

- [webrtc and peerjs: how to choose H264 instead of vp8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788193/webrtc-and-peerjs-how-to-choose-h264-instead-of-vp8)

```
pc.createOffer(function(offer) {
  offer.sdp = removeCodec(offer.sdp, "H264");
  offer.sdp = removeCodec(offer.sdp, "VP9");
  peer_connection.setLocalDescription(offer);
}, function(e) {}, media_constraints);

// removeCodec function code
// https://gist.github.com/tnoho/948be984f9981b59df43
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use a canvas-element to filter the video-streams before transmitting them.